# Way to combine isset and variable assignment in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a cleaner way to do the following:

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    $bar = $foo;
}
```

It just seems redundant to check for a value, then assign it.

Comment: "It just seems redundant to check for a value, then assign it." makes it sound as if you want to NOT check the value first? As for "cleaner" you could try a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use

```
$var or $var = 'default value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly dirty using the `@` operator but:

```
if ($bar = @$foo) { //do something }
```